# Keycode for volume buttons

Tags: linux, audio, mouse, xbindkeys

I'm configuring buttons on my mouse I want to set volume buttons but I don't know the keycode fo volume buttons. I used xbindkeys but didn't work.

Comment: I'm asking for what to write in ~/.xbindkeysrc to controll the volume by pressing mouse buttons

Answer (score 2):

Use `xev`. Click in the window, and it will tell you the number of mousebutton.

```
ButtonPress event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x2a00001,
    root 0x54, subw 0x0, time 421027879, (52,129), root:(1030,148),
    state 0x0, button 3, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x2a00001,
    root 0x54, subw 0x0, time 421027983, (52,129), root:(1030,148),
    state 0x400, button 3, same_screen YES
```

This can be easily translated to xbindkeysrc: `b:3`